Early JsError: Turbo Module Registry.getEnforcing (...) when trying to build android app using new architecture
When app builded successfully i see this Error
Early JsError: Turbo Module Registry.getEnforcing (...): 'PlatformConstants' could not be found. Verify that a module by this name is registered in the native binary. Bridgeless mode: true. Turbo Module interop: true. Modules loaded: ("NativeModules":["TurboModules: "NotFound": ["NativePerformance ObserverCxx","Native PerformanceCxx","PlatformConstants")),
My package.json
"devDependencies": {
"@babel/core": "^7.25.2",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator": "^7.18.6",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.21.0",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.25.4",
"@babel/runtime": "^7.25.6",
"@react-native/eslint-config": "0.75.2",
"@react-native/metro-config": "0.75.2",
"@react-native/typescript-config": "0.75.2",
"@types/react": "^18.3.5",
"@types/react-native-background-timer": "^2.0.2",
"@types/react-native-dotenv": "^0.2.2",
"@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.3.0",
"babel-jest": "^29.7.0",
"babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^5.0.2",
"babel-plugin-transform-remove-console": "^6.9.4",
"eslint": "^9.9.1",
"jest": "^29.7.0",
"prettier": "^3.3.3",
"react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.11",
"react-native-flipper-performance-plugin": "^0.4.0",
"react-test-renderer": "18.3.1",
"typescript": "5.5.4"
},
"dependencies": {
"@expo/config": "^9.0.3",
"@expo/env": "^0.3.0",
"@hookform/resolvers": "^3.9.0",
"@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^2.0.0",
"@react-native-community/checkbox": "^0.5.17",
"@react-native-community/hooks": "^3.0.0",
"@react-native/codegen": "0.75.2",
"@react-native/metro-config": "^0.75.2",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.18",
"@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.11.0",
"@react-three/fiber": "^8.17.6",
"@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.2.7",
"@sentry/react-native": "^5.31.1",
"@shopify/react-native-skia": "^1.3.11",
"@types/lodash": "^4.17.7",
"@types/three": "^0.168.0",
"axios": "^1.7.7",
"base64-arraybuffer": "^1.0.2",
"dayjs": "^1.11.13",
"expo": "51.0.32",
"expo-asset": "^10.0.10",
"expo-av": "~14.0.7",
"expo-constants": "~16.0.2",
"expo-file-system": "~17.0.1",
"expo-font": "~12.0.10",
"expo-gl": "~14.0.2",
"expo-modules-core": "^1.12.24",
"expo-screen-orientation": "~7.0.5",
"expo-sqlite": "~14.0.6",
"immer": "^10.1.1",
"lodash": "^4.17.21",
"react": "18.3.1",
"react-hook-form": "^7.53.0",
"react-icomoon": "^2.5.7",
"react-native": "0.75.2",
"react-native-background-timer": "^2.4.1",
"react-native-ble-manager": "^11.5.5",
"react-native-confirmation-code-field": "^7.4.0",
"react-native-fs": "^2.20.0",
"react-native-geolocation-service": "^5.3.1",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.19.0",
"react-native-just-checkbox": "^2.0.15",
"react-native-logs": "^5.1.0",
"react-native-material-menu": "^2.0.0",
"react-native-radio-buttons-group": "^3.1.0",
"react-native-reanimated": "3.15.1",
"react-native-redash": "^18.1.3",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.10.9",
"react-native-screens": "~3.34.0",
"react-native-svg": "^15.6.0",
"react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.5.0",
"react-native-system-setting": "^1.7.6",
"react-native-toast-notifications": "^3.4.0",
"react-native-ui-datepicker": "^2.0.3",
"react-native-walkthrough-tooltip": "^1.6.0",
"react-native-wifi-reborn": "^4.12.1",
"react-redux": "^9.1.2",
"rn-animated-ellipsis": "^2.1.3",
"three": "0.168.0",
"three-stdlib": "^2.32.2",
"victory-native": "^41.1.1",
"yup": "^1.4.0",
"zustand": "^4.5.5"

Already tried solutions for similar error but with other missing modules. Nothing helped
Picture error

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

The two probable causes are:

An internal error from react native: Currently there’s an issue open with regard to this error showing up. This occurs currently on version 0.76.5. It’s an autolinking bug introduced a while ago when a new feature was being worked on.
A dependency you installed is broken: My scenario came about when I was building a pure C++ turbo module for android and forgot or more or less didn’t know I was to link it to libboost_atomic.so in my CmakeLists.txt. I ported the code from a desktop app I worked on and never did need to link to that specifically. I linked to other things like boost thread and filesystem however. The error that showed the missing .so file showed up in Android Studio’s logcat just before this error showed up. The emulator screen tells you half truths most of the time, so try probing your dependency list to see if any is faulty. Check your logcat output also.

